# SQL Multiple filters in same columns for filtering product

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to filter products from my database.
I want to select products, they meet my conditions.

I have a table with filters and assigned products

| filter | value | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Memory | 2048 | 1 |
| Brand | Samsung | 1 |
| Memory | 2048 | 2 |
| Brand | Xiaomi | 2 |

Now I need to filter Product with (filter = 'Memory' AND value = '2048') AND (filter = 'Brand' AND value = 'Samsung')

This is always returning empty rows.

I am using Mariadb 10.5

Comment: You're basically asking for products that have filter values of both Memory and Brand.  Change the AND to OR (the one inbetween the parenthesis)

Comment: If I use OR, I get result with both products what is not a goot solution.

Comment: I must misunderstand your question, I thought you wanted both results.  What are the results you're expecting?

Comment: I want only product, having Memory = 2048 AND Brand = Samsung,. So the result should be Product with ID 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation, with a `having` clause being sure that all filters pass:

```
select product_id
from t
where (filter = 'Memory' AND value = '2048') or
      (filter = 'Brand' AND value = 'Samsung')
group by product_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

The `count(*) = 2` is ensuring that *both* conditions are met (well, assuming you don't have duplicate rows in the table, which seems like a reasonable assumption).

Comment: Thank you, but this solution is working only for one OR. When I try add another Filter like "display size" and set count(*) = 3, filter is not working anymore

Comment: @PeterValek . . . It should work for as many conditions as you have, and resetting the count in the `having`.

Comment: I have found solution, I have needed filter same "filter value" like Brand = Samsung and Brand = Xiaomi too. So I made it like (filter = 'Brand' AND value = 'Samsung' OR value = 'Xiaomi'). So now it's working, but don't know if it's a good solution.

Comment: @PeterValek . . . This answers the question you asked.  But if you want two possible brands, the logic would be `(filter = 'Brand' and value in ('Samsung', 'Xiaomi'))`.